# WM_COMMAND not being received by Dialog Procedure

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, dialog, contextmenu

I am trying to use a context menu I created for a Dialog Box, but the WM_COMMAND message which is supposed to be sent when I click a menu item is not reaching the Dialog Procedure.

I put an if statement in the message loop to check for `WM_COMMAND`, and it is being registered but not being sent to my Dialog Procedure.

Yes, I am using `if( !IsDialogMessage( hwndListDialog, &msg ) )` to call `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`.

This is how I initialised my context menu:

```
listitemmenu = CreatePopupMenu();

listmenuitem1.cbSize = sizeof( menuitem1 );
listmenuitem1.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
listmenuitem1.fType = MFT_STRING;
listmenuitem1.hSubMenu = NULL;
listmenuitem1.dwTypeData = "Copy Imgur Link";
InsertMenuItem( listitemmenu, 0, true, &listmenuitem1 ); //insert menu item

listmenuitem2.cbSize = sizeof( menuitem1 );
listmenuitem2.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
listmenuitem2.fType = MFT_STRING;
listmenuitem2.hSubMenu = NULL;
listmenuitem2.dwTypeData = "Copy Imgur Delete Link";
InsertMenuItem( listitemmenu, 1, true, &listmenuitem2 ); //insert menu item

listmenuitem3.cbSize = sizeof( menuitem1 );
listmenuitem3.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
listmenuitem3.fType = MFT_STRING;
listmenuitem3.hSubMenu = NULL;
listmenuitem3.dwTypeData = "Rename";
InsertMenuItem( listitemmenu, 2, true, &listmenuitem3 ); //insert menu item

listmenuitem4.cbSize = sizeof( menuitem1 );
listmenuitem4.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
listmenuitem4.fType = MFT_STRING;
listmenuitem4.hSubMenu = NULL;
listmenuitem4.dwTypeData = "Remove from list";
InsertMenuItem( listitemmenu, 3, true, &listmenuitem4 ); //insert menu item
```

This is how I track the menu:

```
TrackPopupMenuEx( listitemmenu, TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_NOANIMATION | TPM_HORIZONTAL | TPM_VERTICAL, cpos.x, cpos.y, ListControl, NULL );
```

This is the switch case that I am *trying* to use to interact with my menu:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        switch( LOWORD(lParam) )
        {
        case 0:
            printf("copy link");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("copy deletion link");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Rename");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Remove");
            break;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: The WM_COMMAND message is sent to *ListControl*.  It that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation for `TrackPopupMenuEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> hwnd [in]
>
> Type: HWND
>
> A handle to the window that owns the shortcut menu. **This window receives all messages from the menu.**

You passed `ListControl` as the `hwnd` parameter, so the `WM_COMMAND` is going to that window, not your dialog box. If you want the `WM_COMMAND` to go to your dialog box, then pass your dialog box as the `hwnd`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (though don't remember exactly, this was a long time ago...) the problem is that you don't specify ID for your menu items. The `WM_COMMAND` that's expected to arrive at your window procedure should carry `lParam` that's equal to the selected item ID. However if you don't specify the item ID it gets `IDC_STATIC` by default, which is an invalid value.

Try the following:

```
listmenuitem1.cbSize = sizeof( menuitem1 );
listmenuitem1.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_ID;
// ...
listmenuitem1.wID = /* the ID you want to see in processing WM_COMMAND */;
// ...
InsertMenuItem( listitemmenu, 0, true, &listmenuitem1 ); //insert menu item
```

P.S. You may also specify `TPM_RETURNCMD` in `TrackPopupMenuEx`, so that the return value will be the selected item ID

Comment: The TPM_RETURNCMD flag makes WM_COMMAND bypass my Dialog Procedure...I've tried this before in a Windows Procedure and was scratching my head at why WM_COMMAND wasn't working.

I just tried adding an ID...did not work unfortunately. WM_COMMAND is still not reaching the Dialog Procedure.

Comment: @Joshua: sorry. I've done such things years ago, don't remember all the details. I can suggest using winspy to see which messages the window actually receives. Also, you talk about dialog procedure, not the actual window procesure (`DlgProc`). Perhaps it decides not to invoke your dialog procedure for `WM_COMMAND` (although this is unlikely). Anyway, using winspy usually helps. Good luck

Comment: Wow Spy++ is terrifically powerful, but it didn't really help me. I see the WM_COMMAND message being posted from my ListControl HWND but I cannot see where it is being posted to...

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution, but it's sort of a ghetto workaround.

Rather than processing `WM_COMMAND` in the Dialog Proc where it cannot be received, I am processing it in the message loop.

```
if( !IsDialogMessage( hwndListDialog, &msg ) )
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
} else {
    if( WM_COMMAND == msg.message )
    {
        switch( LOWORD( msg.wParam ) )
        {
        case 200:
            break;
        case 201:
            break;
        case 202:
            break;
        case 203:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I still hope someone can help me get `WM_COMMAND` inside my Dialog Procedure (especially since `WM_COMMAND` from other dialog controls are reaching the Dialog Proc), but this helps me move forward for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your switch be with wParam and not lParam when handling WM_COMMAND?  For menus, the high word of wParm is 0 and the menu ID is in the low word of wParam. You should also replace ListControl with the handle of your dialog to receive message in TrackPopupMenu as others said.

Comment: I did fix the wParam problem soon after I posted this question. Thanks, though!